# Coq --- Arguments directive

Tags: arguments, coq, implicit-typing

I am reading [Software foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/) book and I came across a command that declares parameters
as implicit:

```
Arguments nil {X}.
```

where, for example:

```
Inductive list (X:Type) : Type :=
| nil : list X
| cons : X -> list X -> list X.
```

However, whenever I try to execute such commands I get the following message:

```
Error: No focused proof (No proof-editing in progress).
```

The same message appears even if I try to compile scripts that come with the book. What could be the problem?

I am using Coq version 8.3pl4 and CoqIDE editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it on my (somewhat old) Coq 8.4 and I don't have any problem with the implicit declaration.
However if I write `Argument` instead of `Arguments` (notice the lack of "s"), I get

```
Error: Unknown command of the non proof-editing mode.
```

Did you correctly spelled it ?

EDIT: sorry, I miss-read your version. It seems that the `Arguments` command has been added post 8.4 (it does not appear [here](http://coq.inria.fr/V8.3pl4/refman/command-index.html) but appears [here](http://coq.inria.fr/V8.4pl1/refman/command-index.html). I advise you update your Coq version if possible, or restrict to using 8.3 `Implicit` related commands (wild guess: `Implicit Arguments foo.`)

Comment: I use `Arguments`. I think I am spelling it correctly since I am using the scripts that come with the book.

Comment: I edited my answer, it seems the command you want to use do not exist in the version of Coq you are using.